# How to use a pointer in a function, in another cpp file?

Tags: c++, pointers, header-files, local-variables

In my U.cpp file I assign values in pointer char array in a function. And then I declared the function in my V.h header file. I want to access the values in pointer char array in another cpp file called S.cpp. If I use global variable in U.cpp, I can access it from S.cpp after declaring in header file with "extern" tag. I couldn't figure it out how can I access the variable in the function. Also I need to assign values of the pointer array to unsigned char array[];

```
//U.cpp
char *ipAdd[4];
char *removeSpaces(char *str)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ')
            str[j++] = str[i];
        i++;
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    return str;
}

void dotSeperatorIP(char* y) {
    removeSpaces(y);
    char *ipAddr = y;
    char *token = strtok(ipAddr, ".");
    // Keep printing tokens while one of the 
    // delimiters present in str[].
    int i = 0;
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        ipAdd[i] = token;
        cout << ipAdd[i] << endl;
        token = strtok(NULL, ".");
        i++;
    }
}

// S.cpp
std::cout << ipAdd[0] << std::endl; // can't access, prints totally a different value

//V.h
int vimonetsetting();
void dotSeperatorIP(char*y);
char *removeSpaces(char *str);

extern char *ipAdd[];
```

EDIT: I managed to access the array by changing the function. Posted as answer. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: g++ -o output U.cpp S.cpp should work.  The reason being each cpp files are compiled into their own translation units. On the other hand, when you declare a variable extern, you are telling the compiler to look for the definition of the variable in another translation unit and it will find it in where you defined it. This is why extern worked for you.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. I am unsure about where you include your header.

Comment: In `dotSeperatorIP`, you have a local variable `ipAddr ` which is not the same as the global one, if that matter.

Comment: The names are a bit confusing I know. They are different. The line with ipAddr is unnecessary, I could use the argument directly in strtok function I guess.@Phil1970

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I changed my dotSeperatorIP function as char** returning. Then, i could access the array from a different .cpp file by calling the function.

```
char** dotSeperatorIP(char* y) {
    removeSpaces(y);
    char *ipAddr = y;
    char *token = strtok(ipAddr, ".");
    // Keep printing tokens while one of the 
    // delimiters present in str[].

    char resultArray[4];
    int i = 0;
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        ipAdd[i] = token;
        //cout << ipAdd[i] << endl;
        token = strtok(NULL, ".");
        i++;
    }

    return ipAdd;
    }
```